# Defining a bijection with binary strings

Tags: combinatorics, binary

Let $n\in\mathbb N$. Then a binary string of length $n$ has the form $a_1a_2...a_n$ such that each $a_i$ is either 0 or 1. Define $E_n$ to be the set of all binary strings of length $n$ with even number of 1's, and define $O_n$ to be the set of all binary strings of length $n$ with odd number 1's.

Define a bijection $f: E_n \to O_n$.

Now, I'm really confused as to how to apply the idea of a bijection in an example like this and I'm not sure how to start. Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest answer as I see it: flip $a_1$. This is a bijection as the inverse function is given by flipping $a_1$.

Comment: That's what I'm concluding as well.. but how would I write that in proper notation to define the bijection?

Comment: $f(e) = e \oplus 1$ perhaps

Comment: @E46 Try something along the lines of "The function $f:E_n\cup O_n\to E_n\cup O_n$ given by $$f(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots a_n) =(1-a_1, a_2, a_3,\ldots,a_n)$$ is its own inverse and therefore a bijection. It clearly sends an element of $E_n$ to an element of $O_n$ and vice versa." But honestly, I would personally accept what I wrote up top (with some fleshing-out) as a full answer if this was on a test. It's not about using the fancy language. Not if you don't have to.

Comment: @Arthur So in reference to that statement, what if $E_4 = 0000$? What would that map to?

Comment: It would map to $1000$. But don't write $E_4=0000$, because that's not what you mean. You mean $0000\in E_4$.

Comment: Would this answer be acceptable too? Define $f: E_n \to O_n$ where $f(a_1a_2...a_n) = b_1a_2..a_n$  such that

$b_1 = 
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $a_1$=1} \\
1, & \text{if $a_1$=0}
\end{cases} $

Comment: @Arthur Sorry forgot to tag you ^

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Start with the case that $n$ is odd, and think about what happens if you simply flip all the 0's to 1's and flip all the 1's to 0's.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Case1: $n$ is odd. Let's say you have $k$ number of $1's$ where $k$ is even. Then send this string to the string obtained by "flipping" $0's$ and $1's$. This has $n-k$ (which is odd) number os $1's$. Check that this is a bijection.

Case 2: $n$ is even. Let's say you have $k$ number of $1's$, with $k$ even. If the left most $a$ is $1$ then consider the string $a_2a_3 \cdots a_n$. This has length $n-1$ (which is even) and $k-1$ number of $1's$ (which is odd). Apply the inverse of the bijection from previous part.

If $a_1=0$ then you have $a_2a_3 \cdots a_n$ a string of length $n-1$ (even) with $k$ number of $1's$. Apply the previous case.